# What do you do with the Basement Entrance Exploration card if you choose not to discard it?

Tags: this-war-of-mine

The Basement Entrance card says after entering:

> Add 5 cards from the Exploration deck to the Unknown deck.
>
> Also, you may discard this card during this Scavenging to draw and resolve 2 Findings cards instead of one.

I do not understand this wording.  Are you supposed to be able to, by default, discard these cards to get 1 Finding?  The quote above seems to imply there is some base behavior allowing me to obtain 1 Finding.  Further, What do you do if you choose not to discard it?  Doesn't it get discarded at some point anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The Basement Entrance gives you more time to search stuff (+5 cards) and you get to find more stuff if you find any (resolve 2 Findings).

When you find the Basement Entrance just set the card aside, add 5 cards to the Unknown deck and later, when you get to resolve a Finding, you can decide to discard the Basement Entrance to resolve two Findings instead of one. You don't need to discard the Basement Entrance on the first Finding, you can decide to hold the car for another Finding.